# is there a way to manually rehash map in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a class `Employee` with two attributes.

```
public class Employee {

    private int empId;
    private String empName;

    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Employee)) return false;
        Employee employee = (Employee) o;
        return getEmpId() == employee.getEmpId() &&
                Objects.equals(getEmpName(), employee.getEmpName());
        //return Objects.equals(getEmpName(), employee.getEmpName());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //return Objects.hash(getEmpId());
        return Objects.hash(getEmpId(), getEmpName());
    }
}
```

I'm using this class as a key in Hashmap.

Now, when I modify the original object `emp` in this case change name on employee object, I could not access the entry I originally saved in map. Only when I roll back the name to it's original value, I could access the object again.

This suggests me that *when I change the name in Employee object, it's hash has changed and it's not stored under the correct bucket in Hashmap*.

```
Map<Employee, String> map = new HashMap<>();;

        // Set Employee with Name Shashi
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setEmpId(1);
        emp.setEmpName("Shashi");

        // Add to Map
        map.put(emp, emp.getEmpName());

        // Modify The Original Employee object's Name
        emp.setEmpName("Shashi Bhushan");

        // This object does not exist as key in map now
        Assert.assertFalse(map.containsKey(emp));

        // Create object with same name(used when creating)
        Employee similarEmployee = new Employee();
        similarEmployee.setEmpId(1);
        similarEmployee.setEmpName("Shashi");

        // Hashcode check will pass, equals will fail
        Assert.assertFalse(map.containsKey(similarEmployee));
        Assert.assertNull(map.get(similarEmployee));

        // Create object with same name(modified name)
        Employee anotherSimilarEmployee = new Employee();
        anotherSimilarEmployee.setEmpId(1);
        anotherSimilarEmployee.setEmpName("Shashi Bhushan");

        // Hashcode check will fail
        Assert.assertFalse(map.containsKey(anotherSimilarEmployee));
        Assert.assertNull(map.get(anotherSimilarEmployee));

        // Now, if I roll back the name, i could again fetch using the new created object as well.
        // Since now this new object will be equivalent to the old object.
        emp.setEmpName("Shashi");
        Assert.assertTrue(map.containsKey(similarEmployee));
        Assert.assertNotNull(map.get(similarEmployee));
```

One solution for **the problem of being able to fetch objects in map** is to make Employee class immutable.

Another theoretical solution I could think of is to rehash the map and keep the modified employee object in it's correct bucket in map but I could not see any method in hashmap that rehashes it. Please suggest if I'm thinking in the right direction or if there is any other solution for this.

P.S. all this is for the purpose of understanding hashmap, so there's no constraint on how to resolve this.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use mutable objects as keys in hash based structures.

Comment: For hash map keys I think you only have 2 options: 1) make it immutable, 2) don't override hashCode and equals, and use the original object instance for lookups

Comment: @boot-and-bonnet's answer is exactly what I wanted to say. And if you do want to change the key, the only safe way is to remove the key from the hashmap, change the key, and then place it back.

Comment: So, if I'll not override equals and hashcode, each new instance of Employee will be different irrespective of if it has same id and name. So far, the suggestion of using only id in methods(ignoring the name altogether) seems valid to me. :)

Comment: Or just use Integer id as the map key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think empId can uniquely identifies a employee.

so `equals` and `hashCode` method only need to handle empId field：

```
   @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Employee)) return false;
        Employee employee = (Employee) o;
        return getEmpId() == employee.getEmpId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getEmpId());
    }
```